# Error When Seeding Users - MVC5 EF6 Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

We're working on our seed method for our database, and have tried a variety of different things to make it work, but it keeps erroring out.

Our seed method is

```
    protected override void Seed(WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Admin"))
        {
            var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
            var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
            var role = new IdentityRole {Name = "Admin"};

            manager.Create(role);
        }

        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Admin"))
        {
            var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
            var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = "Admin"};

            manager.Create(user, "ChangeItAsap!");
            manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        }
    }
```

The error is

```
The type 'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.
```

With the following line being the cause

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
```

I'm not entirely sure what could be causing this, as I've never ran into this issue in the past. any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

Here is the definition

```
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string> { }
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string> { }
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string> { }

// Must be expressed in terms of our custom Role and other types:
public class ApplicationUser
    : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin,
    ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Add any custom User properties/code here
    }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRole()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public ApplicationRole(string name)
        : this()
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    // Add any custom Role properties/code here
}


public class ApplicationDbContext
    : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,
    string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

// Most likely won't need to customize these either, but they were needed because we implemented
// custom versions of all the other types:
public class ApplicationUserStore
    : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string,
        ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole,
        ApplicationUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string>,
    IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationUserStore()
        : this(new IdentityDbContext())
    {
        base.DisposeContext = true;
    }

    public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

    public class ApplicationRoleStore
: RoleStore<ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserRole>,
IQueryableRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string>,
IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string>, IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationRoleStore()
        : base(new IdentityDbContext())
    {
        base.DisposeContext = true;
    }

    public ApplicationRoleStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `ApplicationUser`.  That error message suggests that it doesn't inherit from `IdentityUser`

Comment: I've included the `ApplicationUser` definition

Comment: Also having this issue right now and not sure what's going on. ApplicationUser class definitely inherits from IdentityUser, my only difference is we've changed ApplicationUser to use int id's rather than strings.

Comment: I figured this out on my end, did you customize your ID's?